# Iraq download server for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I'm from Iraq. I have Ubuntu 16.04 . From "Software& Updates", I'm trying to set the download server to Iraq, but I found no such server.

Is this possible? Should I use a server for nearby country?

Comment: Look for a close one that has good Connection (>1Gbps) and which is up to date: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors. I'd suggest using Turkish or Iranian mirror.

Comment: Iraq does not have a mirror, as @pLumo suggested, try a nearby mirror like Turkish or Iranian. Personally, I, once, tried Turkish mirrors and they work well.

Comment: Thank you. Kuwait server works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying some servers I found that [Kuwait Server](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntu.archive.kw.zain.com-archive) works well.